# Ajax keeps sending null values to the method even tho facebook is giving me the requested data

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a login through Facebook, in the console it shows that I'm getting the requested data (email, first_name ...) but ajax keeps sending null data to the PHP method.

here's the ajax code:

```
function saveUserData() {
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', function(response){

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Auth/fb_auth',
                    data: {response: JSON.stringify(response)},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        if(data['state'] == 'ok'){
                            window.location.href ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

and this is how I get the data in the method:

```
$response  = json_decode($this->input->post('response'), true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need to stringify stuff with `$.ajax`, it does that for you. Also, you can use `$.post` instead:

```
function saveUserData() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', function(response){
        $.post({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Auth/fb_auth',
            data: response,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data['state'] === 'ok'){
                    window.location.href ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```